# creating webview in fragment, but webview appears to be blank

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, android-webview

im quite new to android studio, and i am facing this problem where i've adopted other's codes for applying webview in my fragment, and currently my webview when tested on the emulator appears a blank page instead of the url that i've set. greatly appreaciatte for your help :)

the xml and java are as below

the xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1.0">


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The Java

```
public class FavoritesFragment extends Fragment {

    WebView myWebView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup        container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favorites,container,false);
        myWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        return view;

    }
}
```

Comment: have you set permission ? <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

Comment: @AmodGokhale Yes i have set the permission in my manifest file, is there anything i need to do in my MainActivity java, cause i created a bottom navigation bar to other fragments

Comment: @AmodGokhale and the codes in the java leads to the activity_main.xml Framelayout in duplicates of this code
    if(i==R.id.Bottombaritemone) {
    
PeopleFragment f = new PeopleFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f).commit();
               
 }

Comment: @AmodGokhale is alright thank you for your time solved it, wasnt the problem in this codes thanks